# Как задать условие кратности?

Tags: python

Мне нужно найти среднее арифметическое всех введенных с клавиатуры чисел, кратных 2 и 3 одновременно. Как проверить кратность?

Код:

```
arr = [] 
n = int(input("Введите количество элементов : ")) 
for i in range(0, n): 
    ele = int(input()) 
    arr.append(ele)  
a = sum(arr) / n 
print(a)
```

Comment: Кратный 2 и 3 одновременно == кратный 6

Comment: Код написанный  снизу делит на число n введенное пользователем, а нужно разделить на n кратное 3 и 2. Не подскажешь как сделать деление на n удовлетворяющих условию?

Comment: @GeTrennT, например, `a = sum(arr) / len(arr)`. (`len` возвращает длину списка).

Comment: Если вопрос для вас закрыт, то отметьте ответ @Pro Task как решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки кратности можно использовать оператор `%` (аналог `mod` в других языках). Он возвращает остаток от деления первого операнда на второй. Пример: 12 % 5 = 2.

Соответственно, если остаток от деления первого числа на второе равен 0, то первое число делится на второе.

Таким образом, код приобретает следующий вид:

```
arr = []
n = int(input("Введите количество элементов: "))
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input())
    if ele % 2 == 0 and ele % 3 == 0:
        arr.append(ele)
a = sum(arr) / n
print(a)
```

Кстати, если вам нужно найти среднее арифметическое, то `sum(arr)` нужно делить не на `n`, а на `len(arr)`:

```
a = sum(arr) / len(arr)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, но этот код делит на число n введенное пользователем, а нужно разделить на n кратное 3 и 2.

Comment: То есть нужно, чтобы n был вроде n = [3, 12, 10, 6]. Из этого списка взять только 12 и 6? Тогда не совпадает задача с тем, что в заголовке написано. Либо я неправильно понимаю

Comment: Уже всё, мне помогли решить задачу используя  a = sum(arr) / len(arr).